# Find the 'Pattern' subtotals of the number of ways of choosing k objects from n types of objects

Tags: combinatorics

I recently answered this StackOverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77854835/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-ways-to-choose-y-items-from-at-most-x-groups-effi/77855848#77855848 with a conjecture I constructed just from testing a bunch of values with a computer program I wrote to explore the problem. I have some confidence that the conjecture is true, because it seems unlikely that if it were not true, then some of the 'Pattern' subtotals would be wrong, probably then giving incorrect totals. I'm no expert in combinatorics so I thought I'd ask the experts. I feel like there could be a new theorem here waiting to be proven which could have practical usefulness.

Suppose you have $n$ types of objects from which you want to choose $k$ objects. Call a 'Pattern' an increasing sequence of counts of the objects of different types. How many different ways are there of choosing the $m$ objects that give a target Pattern?

For example, suppose I want to choose $5$ items from $3$ types such that it has a Pattern $(0, 1, 4)$. This could be none of type $1$, one of type $2$, and four of type $3$ or any permutation of the types such as none of type $3$, one of type $1$, and four of type $2$. In this case there are $30$ distinct ways. If I take none of type $1$, one of type $2$, and four of type $3$, then there are $5$ ways to make the choice.

```
33332, 33323, 33233, 32333, 23333
```

There are $3! = 6$ ways to permute the types, so in total there must be $5\times 6 = 30$ ways that produce the Pattern $(0, 1, 4)$. I can add up all the Pattern subtotals and must get $n^k$.

```
3 : 0 0 5 
30 : 0 1 4 
60 : 0 2 3 
60 : 1 1 3 
90 : 1 2 2 
Total 243 : 3^5 = 243
```

The conjecture I posed in my StackOverflow answer claims that the number of ways of choosing a Pattern $(a_1, ... , a_n)$ is equal to:

$$n! \frac{(a_1 + ... + a_n)!}{a_1! ...a_n!\times D_1! ... D_m!}$$

where there are $m$ distinct $a_i$ which occur $D_i$ times.
E.g. for $(1, 2, 3, 3)$, $[D_1, D_2, D_3] = [1, 1, 2]$, for $(2, 3, 3, 3)$ $[D_1, D_2] = [1, 3]$.

I obtained the formula without the $D_i$ from well-known combinatorics theorems which works when there are no duplicate numbers in the Pattern, but I have no idea why the equation with the $D_i$ works (meaning for the most part only that the subtotals add up to the correct total) for all the many test cases I tried. I thought someone might enjoy having a go at making or finding a proven theorem out of this. Thanks.

Comment: Your formula contains the expression $(a_1+\ldots+a_n)!$. Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, isn't $a_1+\ldots+a_n=k$? We're choosing $k$ objects, so the sum of the counts of the types must be the total number of objects chosen?

Comment: Yes a1 + … + an = k. I didn't use k in the Stackoverflow post, that's all.

Comment: Your formula is correct, you reinvented multinomial coefficients https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients

Comment: I wrote a blog article about this that might interest you: https://blog.plover.com/math/yahtzee.html

Answer (score 0):

For $p\in \omega$, let $p=\{0,\ldots, p-1\}$.

Fix a pattern $a=(a_0, \ldots, a_{n-1})$. Fix a permutation $\sigma:n\to n$ and note that this yields a way of assigning a type to a count of that type. That is, we can choose $a_{\sigma(i)}$ items of type $i$ for $i\in n$. However, some of these permutations will yield to the same counts of each type. For example, if $a_0=a_1=p$, then the identity permutation and the transposition $\tau$ which sends $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $0$ both yield $p$ items of types $0$ and $1$.

So we want to group these permutations based on when they produce the same counts of each type and when they don't. In other words, for a fixed $\sigma$, for how many $\tau$ will it be true that $(a_{\tau\circ \sigma(i)})_{i\in n}=(a_{\sigma(i)})_{i\in n}$? This is exactly where your $D_i$ come in. For $j\in k$, let $$E_j=\{i\in n:a_i=j\}.$$ Let $|E_j|=b_j$. Then there are $\prod_{j\in k}b_j!$ ways to pick a $\tau$ so that $(a_{\tau\circ \sigma(i)})_{i\in n}=(a_{\sigma(i)})_{i\in n}$, because $\tau$ has this property iff it permutes the members of each $E_j$ among themselves. This is slightly different than the way you've labeled things, because you've referenced the $m$ distinct $a_i$ values. Here, that's just the $j$ for which $E_j\neq \varnothing$, and including the other $E_j$ just includes extra $0!=1$ factors in the product.

So there are $\chi:=\frac{n!}{\prod_{i\in n}b_i!}$ ways to assign the counts in the pattern to the different types, because we can partition the set of all $n!$ permutations into subsets which induce the same count types, and each element of the partition has $\prod_{i\in n}b_i!$ members.

So now fix a permutation $\sigma$ that gives us count types. We need to know how many ways there are to choose $(l_j)_{j\in k}$ so that $$|\{j\in k:l_j=i\}|=a_{\sigma(i)}$$ for all $i\in n$. But this is $$\binom{k}{a_{\sigma(0)},\ldots,a_{\sigma(n-1)}} = \frac{k!}{\prod_{i\in n}a_{\sigma(i)}!} = \frac{k!}{\prod_{i\in n}a_i!},$$ since we're just partitioning the $k$ indices into $n$ subsets which have cardinalities $a_0,\ldots, a_{n-1}$ (in some order). So we get $$\binom{n}{b_0,\ldots,b_{k-1}}\cdot \binom{k}{a_0,\ldots, a_{n-1}},$$ as you've written. The first factor gives the number of ways to assign the counts to the types, and the second gives the number of ways to fill out the sequence to achieve those counts.